# Custom ContextMenu not displaying in MX TextArea

Tags: apache-flex, textarea, contextmenu, flex-mx

Been tearing my hair out for ages trying to get my custom ContextMenu to apply to a TextArea, It will just display the default (copy, paste ect...).

```
        import mx.events.FlexEvent;

        public var nm:NativeMenu = new NativeMenu();
        public var cm:ContextMenu = new ContextMenu();

        protected function windowedapplication1_creationCompleteHandler(event:FlexEvent):void
        {
            cm.clipboardMenu = true;

            var cmi:ContextMenuItem = new ContextMenuItem("ctest");
            cm.addItem(cmi);

            TA.contextMenu = cm;
        }
```

given TA is an mx TextArea in MXML

i'm really stumped!

Comment: Found a solution:

    var txt:TextField = TA.mx_internal::getTextField() as TextField;
    txt.contextMenu = cm;

placed after "TA.contextMenu = cm;" will allow the custom elements to show

Comment: Hi @bigtallbill, and welcome on SO, post your solution as an answer and check it as a solved, or delete question. Try not to leave questions in open state.

Comment: I tried but there was a 24 hour limit for new users. luckily andrewpthorp posted the answer :)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Just to put a full set of code for everyone to see:

```
var cm:ContextMenu = new ContextMenu();

var menuitem:ContextMenuItem = new ContextMenuItem("Check Spelling");
menuitem.addEventListener(ContextMenuEvent.MENU_ITEM_SELECT, handleContextMenuEvent);
mainMenu.addItem(menuitem);

textArea.contextMenu = mainMenu;
var txt:TextField = textArea.mx_internal::getTextField() as TextField;
txt.contextMenu = mainMenu;
```

Hope this helps!